# Loading user's info in the side menu ionic 2

Tags: angular, binding, ionic2

I am trying to add the user's info to my side menu from '../providers/data'

This the page app.html

```
<ion-menu side="right" [content]="content">
<ion-content class="no-scroll">
 <div class="menu-bg-color" >
        <ion-list no-lines >
            <div *ngIf="user">
            <ion-item class="menu-top">
                <img src="{{user.img}}" width="80" height="80">
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{user.email}}</p>
            </ion-item>
            </div>
            <div class="divider-long"></div>
            <ion-item item-left class="ions-item" *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
               <ion-icon class="icon-style"  name="{{p.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
                <h3 class="text-menu">{{p.title}}</h3>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<!--What's my root? remember the this.rootPage?-->
<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="true"></ion-nav>
```

i can import the user's info to the other pages with this function:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadingProvider.show();
    this.dataProvider.getCurrentUser().subscribe((user) => {
      this.loadingProvider.hide();
      this.user = user;
      console.log("page profile : " + user.name)
    });
  }
```

The question is: how can i import the user's info to the page app.html(side menu page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.loadingProvider.show();
this.dataProvider.getCurrentUser().subscribe((user) => {
  this.loadingProvider.hide();
  this.user = user;
  console.log("page profile : " + user.name)
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got this error: Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined

Comment: The error is not from `ngOnInit`. test the method with just a console log.

Comment: The problem is the loading of user's info. I think the side menu will be created before the importation of data from dataprovider

Comment: You can move side menu to another component.